# Is There A Way i can insert 'Ronald' Into StudentEntry?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

The Purpose is to enter in Ronald and get all of the information inside of the

Ronald Variable , using the method "INSERT" to make this happen , im stuck and

am looking on suggestions on how to do this ,

```
#the class/object
class Jurystudent:
    def __init__(self, gpa , First , Last, NUMOFCLASSES,gradelvl):
        self.gpa = gpa
        self. First = First
        self.Last = Last
        self.Numberofclasses = NUMOFCLASSES
        self.gradelvl = gradelvl
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.gpa)+","+str(self.First)+ ","+str(self.Last)+","+str(self.Numberofclasses)+ ","+str(self.gradelvl)

#The function that inserts the result being searched into the result box

def insert():


Ronald = Jurystudent(4.0,'Ronald', 'Colyar' , 6 , 10)

print(Ronald)





#Gui
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#Window 
root = Tk()

#Entry 
StudentEntry=ttk.Entry(root)
StudentEntry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky =W)

#Button
SearchButton=ttk.Button(root , text ='Search')
SearchButton.grid(row = 1 , column= 1 , sticky =W)
SearchButton.bind('<Button-1>', insert)
#Result
Result  =ttk.Entry(root)

Result.grid(row= 1 , column = 2 , sticky= W )
```

this is a way i can search for the students at my school information.

ive tried using the .get function to get the value of the studententry entry

and use the insert function to place the value over to the Result entry ,  it

gives me a direct insertion of what i place in the studententry entry , for

example , if i were to put Ronald.gpa  into the entry , I would like to get 4.0

in return into the result entry , instead im getting 'Ronald'

Comment: "im stuck" - with what, exactly? What have you tried? Please edit your question to ask a specific question and explain what you've tried.

Comment: ive tried using the .get function to get the value of the studententry entry and use the insert function to place the value over to the Result entry ,  it gives me a direct insertion of what i place in the studententry entry , for example , if i were to put Ronald.gpa  into the entry , I would like to get 4.0 in return into the result entry , instead im getting 'Ronald'

Comment: Ronald is the instance, the variables in the class are instance objects. print(Ronald.First, Ronald.Last), etc.

Comment: what i am trying to do is find a soultion to place those values , into the Result entry , i know how to print them , i just dont know a correct way to insert them inside of the Result entry , ive defined the __str__ method inside my class, this makes me able to print all of the attributes of ronald , all at once just by printing ronald

Comment: The button would have to be bound to a function that would get() the "Ronald", and then insert the info already in the Ronald instance, into the StudentEntry entry (see get() and insert() at the above link, as well as how to connect a button click to a function on the Button tkinterbook page there).

Comment: how would you do this ? , i already have a function listed as 'insert' with no block of code inside of it , what parameters would it take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to do here after reading this question and [the one you asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171808/does-the-get-function-work-on-created-objects). You have a *"database"* (of sorts) of people who all have their own metadata and you want a way of displaying it in a tkinter window.

This is relatively simple and I think you're seriously, **seriously** over complicating things in your code.

The below example does what I *think* you need:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.data = [{"Name": "Alpha", "Var1": "3", "Var2": "1", "Var3": "4"},
                 {"Name": "Beta", "Var1": "1", "Var2": "5", "Var3": "9"},
                 {"Name": "Charlie", "Var1": "2", "Var2": "6", "Var3": "6"}
            ]
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.trace("w", self.callback)
        self.entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.labels = [(Label(self.root, text="Name"),Label(self.root)),(Label(self.root, text="Var1"),Label(self.root)),(Label(self.root, text="Var2"),Label(self.root)),(Label(self.root, text="Var3"),Label(self.root))]
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            self.labels[i][0].grid(row = i+1, column=0)
            self.labels[i][1].grid(row = i+1, column=1)
    def callback(self, *args):
        for i in self.data:
            if i["Name"] == self.var.get():
                for c in self.labels:
                    c[1].configure(text=i[c[0].cget("text")])

App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So let's break this down.

First of all, I'm using a different data structure. In the above example we have a `list` of `dictionary`s. This is a pretty typical way of getting a *"database like"* structure in Python.

I'm then using a different method for actually calling the search, opting to use a binding on the `variable` assigned to `textvariable` within the `Entry` widget. This means that every time the `Entry` widget is written to a `variable` is updated, whenever this `variable` is updated we get a callback to the `callback()` function, this section can be seen below:

```
        self.var = StringVar() #we generate a tkinter variable class here
        self.var.trace("w", self.callback) #we setup the callback here
        self.entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.var) #and we assign the variable to the Entry widget here
```

Next up I essentially create 6 `Label` widgets in a 2 wide, 3 high grid. The `Label`s on the left act as an identifier and the `Label`s on the right are left blank for later. This is all pretty standard tkinter stuff which has been covered too many times on this site.

The last, and possibly hardest to understand section, is the actual callback, so let's look at it line-by-line:

```
for i in self.data:
```

This `for` loop simply cycles through every dictionary, assigning it to `i`.

```
    if i["Name"] == self.var.get():
```

This `if` statement says **IF the value of the `Entry` widget IS EQUAL TO the value of the `Name` key in the dictionary we're currently looping through THEN True**.

If the above check comes back as `True` we then loop through `self.labels` which contains the `Label` widgets we generated earlier.

```
                    c[1].configure(text=i[c[0].cget("text")])
```

Lastly, we set the second value in each `tuple` of the `list` (The blank `Label` widgets) to be the value of the dictionary we're looping through where the key matches the text of the identifier variable.

The above accomplishes what I *think* you want, you just need to amend your data to the format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dictionary.  A very simplified example

```
class Jurystudent:
    def __init__(self, gpa , First , Last, NUMOFCLASSES,gradelvl):
        self.gpa = gpa
        self. First = First
        self.Last = Last
        self.Numberofclasses = NUMOFCLASSES
        self.gradelvl = gradelvl

dict_of_instances={}
Ronald = Jurystudent(4.0,'Ronald', 'Colyar' , 6 , 10)
dict_of_instances["Ronald"]=Ronald
dict_of_instances["George"] = Jurystudent(3.2,'George', 'Washington' , 5 , 11)

## simulate "George" entered in Entry and
## "Ronald" entered as another, separate request
for student in ["George", "Ronald"]:
    print("\nPrinting info for", student)
    first=dict_of_instances[student].First
    last=dict_of_instances[student].Last
    print("     ", first, last)
    num_classes=dict_of_instances[student].Numberofclasses
    print("     ", num_classes, dict_of_instances[student].gradelvl)
```

Comment: This only prints to consle , im trying to search for  the 'Ronald' variable and when i hit submit , '4.0 , first ,last ect' should be returned into the result entry .inside my GUI window , This programm is suppose to be a information searcher , i want to be able to create my school a new system to search for students name , and get the information of that student