# How can i improve this data like structure in python?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

This is a data base like structure for students i created in python , i was wonder if you guys can take a look at this code and give me some suggestions on how to get better writing good code(meaning that looks good and that is easy to understand , i just started coding around 2-3 weeks ago) any thing you guys suggest i will take into consideration , im just trying to improve :)

```
#Our Gui TOOls 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Window
root = Tk()
#Not allowing the window to be resized 
root.resizable(height = False , width = False)
#title of window when we get more things in the window 
root.title(string = 'Ronald')
#The object /class
class Students:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.data = [{"Student Info": "Ronald Colyar", "Gpa": "4.0", "GradeLVL": "10", "NumOfClasses": "6" , 'Parents number': '773-567-2791'},
                 {"Student Info": "Beta", "Gpa": "1", "GradeLVL": "5", "NumOfClasses": "9", 'Parents number': '773-867-2791'},
                 {"Student Info": "Charlie", "Gpa": "2", "GradeLVL": "6", "NumOfClasses": "6", 'Parents number': '773-566-2791'}
            ]


#Container (very vaguly speaking )
        self.var = StringVar()
#track what is being put inside entry
        self.var.trace("w", self.callback)
#The entry across 2 columns in row 0
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

#All of the labels that correspond the the information in self.data
        self.labels = [(ttk.Label(self.root, text="Student Info"),ttk.Label(self.root)),(ttk.Label(self.root, text="Gpa"),ttk.Label(self.root)),(ttk.Label(self.root, text="GradeLVL"),ttk.Label(self.root)),(ttk.Label(self.root, text="NumOfClasses"),ttk.Label(self.root)),(ttk.Label(self.root, text="Parents number"),ttk.Label(self.root))]
#spacing the labels out in the window by the amount of them        

        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            self.labels[i][0].grid(row = i+1, column=0)
            self.labels[i][1].grid(row = i+1, column=1)
#if the entry  matches the data , display the data.

    def callback(self, *args):
        for i in self.data:
            #if the data matches evaluates to true
            if i["Student Info"] == self.var.get():
                #execute if data matches 
                for c in self.labels:
                    c[1].configure(text=i[c[0].cget("text")])
#Calling our object inside of root
Students(root)
#Constant loop of our window
root.mainloop()
```

3rd week programming how do you guys think im learning , am i behind for 3 weeks , or am i kind of on track for becoming a good software developer , also im 16 so i have a few years to master these skills.

Comment: The code is looking good, but try to add this to code review section [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: is this ok for just starting to code in 2-4 weeks?

Comment: Yeah man, you have knowledge of class which is going to help when you start building more complex applications, plus you comment your code so that others can read and understand without over-commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is pretty well laid out ([if I do say so myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47201294/4528269)) in terms of readability and Pythonic best practice.

There are a few subjective improvements which could be made.

The first of which is the use of `enumerate()` here:

```
for i in range(len(self.labels)):
    self.labels[i][0].grid(row = i+1, column=0)
    self.labels[i][1].grid(row = i+1, column=1)
```

Instead of the above we can use something like the below:

```
for c, i in enumerate(self.labels, 1):
    i[0].grid(row = c+1, column=0)
    i[1].grid(row = c+1, column=1)
```

`enumerate()` takes a list and returns a tuple with an index number associated with the value in the list, so in this case where we have declared that the first index value should be `1` we get a data structure returned like the below:

```
[(1, (ttk.Label(self.root, text="Student Info"),ttk.Label(self.root))),(2, (ttk.Label(self.root, text="Gpa"),ttk.Label(self.root))), . . . ]
```

This means we can forego having to use a separate counting variable and the confusion that can result from that.

We can also implement a system where by we can have an *"autocomplete"* functionality with the searches, we can do this by modifying the below line:

```
if i["Student Info"] == self.var.get():
```

To:

```
if i["Student Info"][:len(self.var.get())] == self.var.get() and ([x["Student Info"][:len(self.var.get())] for x in self.data].count(self.var.get()) == 1 or i["Student Info"] == self.var.get()):
```

Which looks scary and like there's a lot going on but let's take a look at it closer.

We use string splicing to pull back the first part of the name string up to the length of the string in the `Entry` field and compare it against the value in the `Entry` to see whether we get a match, if we do then the program then has to evaluate whether there are any other records which would match this (for example if we had `Ron` and `Ronald` registered we don't want it to autocomplete until we're sure that the user wants `Ron` or `Ronald`). To do this we use an `or` clause on our `if` statement:

```
([x["Student Info"][:len(self.var.get())] for x in self.data].count(self.var.get()) == 1 or i["Student Info"] == self.var.get()):
```

This means that if either of the two conditions return `True` we will proceed with the block of code underneath the statement. The first half of the `or` statement uses list comprehension to return a list of the name strings up to the length of the value in the `Entry` and then counts how many of those match the value in the `Entry` (for example, if we had `Ron` and `Ronald` and typed in `"Ro"` this would return `2`) and then checks to see if that count is equal to `1`. If it is then we return `True` because there can't possibly be any other matches in our data. The second half checks if the value in the `Entry` exactly matches anything in our data, if we didn't do this then `Ron` would never be returned where we had both `Ron` and `Ronald` because `Ron` will always return a count of `2` for the previous statement.

Lastly, if you wanted you could move over your data into another file, like a `.json` or `.csv` (this would be subjectively easier with a `.json` file than `.csv`) so that it didn't clutter up your program. You'd then need to import the data to be used within your program. This has been explained a lot on SO, so you should be able to find a question which helps you.

Comment: You think i can ask a few questions via email?